# Load social buttons when access is allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-social-plugins, google-plus-one

I want to load social buttons only if the user has access to it. i.e we are in an org. where social access is not given to everyone. I want to load the buttons if that user has access to those sites like fb, twitter, google+.I have the code for the buttons for social sharing.

Comment: I am not much sure, but you this can be identified if you script loading calls results with success or failure...based on this you can identify if user has access or and you can handle sharing button display..

Comment: can you explain in more detail..

Comment: Do you have any reference code on which i can work further??

Comment: <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://trial.com" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=">Share</a>

Comment: this button is for fb sharing.